# SQL Server 2008 Mirroring Pauses without warning

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

I have several databases mirroring with a witness.  All 3 machines are local to our network and have generous nics.  Monitoring the mirroring, it does not seem like there is a lot of network traffic.

Yet some of the databases' mirroring is pausing without warning.  When I restart them, they pause again almost immediately.

What could be the culprit?

---

**EDIT**:

Well, now it looks like they are mirroring again...when I went into mirroring manager and tried restarting them, it succeeded now--whereas yesterday it would automatically pause again.

Anyone know why mirrors would just pause? Wouldn't they just failover?

Comment: What does the mirroring monitor say? (Right click database name, tasks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you query the `sys.database_mirroring` catalog view you should find out the status of database mirroring from the mirroring_state field.  Try this:

```
select 
    DB_NAME(database_id),
    mirroring_state
from sys.database_mirroring
```

When it "pauses", what does the `mirroring_state` show?  Here is a legend:

**0** = Suspended

**1** = Disconnected from the other partner

**2** = Synchronizing

**3** = Pending Failover

**4** = Synchronized

**5** = The partners are not synchronized. Failover is not possible now.

**6** = The partners are synchronized. Failover is potentially possible. For information about the requirements for failover see, Synchronous Database Mirroring (High-Safety Mode).

**NULL** = Database is inaccessible or is not mirrored.